# Enable or visible textbox by radiobutton

Tags: vb.net

I want to enable or visible a textbox when the user check the radiobutton like a yes\no questions if the answer is no the textbox will be enable or visible.
Before I forget all these in gridview

Thank you

Comment: Post the code which you have tried.

Comment: Code, and also tag your question with the technology you are using (e.g. informs, asp, mvc...)

Answer (score 1):

In your Grid's **RowDataBound** event find your controls first. Then set the visibility of the textbox with the condition you need.

```
Protected Sub gvTimeSlots_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvTimeSlots.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim RadioButton1 As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButton = e.Row.FindControl("RadioButton1")
        Dim TextBox1 As System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox = e.Row.FindControl("TextBox1")
    If RadioButton1.Value="Yes" Then
       TextBox1.Enabled = True
       // If you want to set the visibility use
       TextBox1.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I have many columns in the gridview, 3 columns for yes(the cloumn name), no and reason.

Comment: I have many columns in the gridview, 3 columns for yes(the cloumn name), no and reason. I used your code but it doesn`t work & I used rowdatabound yesterday but the result is doesn`t change. I put 2 radiobuttons in to clolumns & they have the same groupname. do you have another solution? thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I used many solutions I found them in the internet & this one of them

Protected Sub reject_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

```
    Dim rbd As RadioButton = CType(sender, RadioButton)
    Dim grdrow As GridViewRow = CType(rbd.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)

    Dim reject As RadioButton = CType(grdrow.Cells(9).Controls(0).FindControl("reject"), RadioButton)
    Dim t1 As TextBox = CType(grdrow.Cells(9).Controls(0).FindControl("t1"), TextBox)

    If reject.Checked = True Then
        t1.Visible = True

End Sub
```

when I check the radiobutton it will unchecked when AutoPostedBack True (for the 2 solutions)
my gridview name gvorders